# How to create an input method in C++ with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, input, methods, cin

I want to create an input method that creates two ints with Pointers.
It would be nice if you could help me or give me any tips. :)

my method:

```
void inputTest(int* x, int* y) {
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
}
```

my main:

```
int *x = 0;
int *y = 0;
cout << "Input: " << endl;


//set input from user x,y with input method 
inputTest(x,y);
```

Comment: `int *x = 0;` is not doing what you think it's doing

Comment: Can you clarify - do you want the `inputTest` method to both *allocate* (create) and *assign* `x` and `y`, or just to assign values to them from the `cin` stream?

Comment: I believe you have a wrong idea about pointers. maybe a [good read](https://gist.github.com/ericandrewlewis/720c374c29bbafadedc9) can help.

Comment: I want to assign new values from the cin stream for x and y

Comment: @Coder95 You can use references instead of pointers, if you want x and y changed inside inputTest

Comment: why do you think you need to use pointers? or why do you want to use pointers? Anything can be done with pointers, but almost anything can be done without pointers too

Comment: I'm new to pointers so I want to try it that way.. :)

Comment: You want references : `int x = 0; int y = 0;` and then `inputTest(int& x, int& y)`. Pointers must point to something to be usefull.

Comment: @Coder95 I'm sorry to disappoint you, but in C++ we use smart pointers. If you want to feel really low-levelly, use C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you want to read `int`s, not `int*`s, so you need to dereference the pointers:

```
void inputTest(int* x, int* y) {
    cin >> *x;
    cin >> *y;
}
```

Then you need to pass valid pointers to the function - yours are *null pointers* and point nowhere at all.
The best way to do this is to first create two `int`s and then acquire their locations with the "address-of" operator, `&`.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
cout << "Input: " << endl;
inputTest(&x, &y);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'm new to pointers so I want to try it that way.. :)

Ok, then first lesson: Do not use pointers when you don't have to. Pointers can cause the most nasty bugs that you dont get without them.

Next: Pointers are just pointers. The can point to something. A `int*` **can** point to an `int`. Your pointers do not point to anything meaningful.

To store integer values you need `int`s somewhere. Having pointers pointing somewhere is not sufficient. Once you have a `int`, eg `int x;` then `&x` will give you a `int*` namely the address of `x` (`&` is called the address-of operator, but dont get confused, `&` can have a different meaning, see below). If you have the pointer, `int* p = &x;` then you can dereference the pointer to get back x: `*p = 5;` will set the value of `x` to `5`. Using that you could write

```
void inputTest(int* x, int* y) {
    std::cin >> *x;    
    std::cin >> *y;
}
int main() {
   int x,y;
   inputTest(&x,&y);
   std::cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

**BUT** (would like to make it even more bold, because it really is a big "but"). There is an alternative and this is what you should use here. Pointers as parameters are useful when "not pointing anywhere" is an allowed parameter. For a fucntion that wants to read input from user and store that somewhere an invalid pointer is of little use. Better is to disallow such invalid input and use references:

```
void inputTest(int& x, int& y) {
    std::cin >> x;    
    std::cin >> y;
}
int main() {
   int x,y;
   inputTest(x,y);
   std::cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

I feel a bit bad for writing this answer, because when you are completely new to pointers, reading an answer here will not be enough to get a proper understanding. Get a book and read it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to dereference the pointer in order to assign a value to the pointed location in memory.

```
void inputTest(int* xptr, int* yptr) {
    cin >> *xptr;
    cin >> *yptr;
}
```

`int* x = 0` creates a pointer to location 0 in memory. Instead, we want to allocate memory, and then point to that memory. We can initialize x as `int x = 0` and then get a pointer to it by using &x.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
cout << "Input: " << endl;
inputTest(&x,&y);
```

You can also use references...

```
void inputTest(int& x, int& y) {
    cin >> x;
    cin >> y;
}

int x = 0;
int y = 0;
cout << "Input: " << endl;
inputTest(x,y);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may choose one of two ways:

1. Declare your variables as regular `int`s and pass their addresses to the function `inputTest()` which is the recommended way.
2. Declare your variables as pointers to `int`s and allocate valid memory to them.

Example for approach 1:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
cout << "Input: " << endl;


//set input from user x,y with input method 
inputTest(&x, &y);
```

Example for approach 2:

```
int *x = new int;
int *y = new int;
cout << "Input: " << endl;


//set input from user x,y with input method 
inputTest(x,y);
```

and don't forget to release/delete the allocated memory when you're done.

Also you should use:

```
cin >> *x;
cin >> *y;
```

inside your function.

Comment: You mean _delete_, not _free_ since you newed and not malloced.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution with pointers

With `int *x = 0` you have only declared a pointer which points to nowhere. And pointer shall store only 'pointing' information, not a data itself.

```
    void inputTest(int* x, int* y) {
        cin >> *x; // dereference a pointer to get to the 'real' variable
        cin >> *y; // this is also a disadventage of pointers, pointer can point to nowhere, 
                   // and your programwould crach in that situation
    }

    int main()
    {
       int x = 0; // declare a normal variable, instead of a pointer
       int y = 0; 

       cout << "Please insert an input: " << endl;

       inputTest(&x, &y); // pass addresses that point to your variables

       cout << "Your input: " << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
```

### Solution with references

You can also achive this same functionality with references. Maybe you will like them.

```
    void inputTest(int& x, int& y) // mind & instead of *
    {
        cin >> x; // no need of dereferencing,
        cin >> y;
    }

    int main()
    {
       int x = 0; // a normal variable
       int y = 0; 

       cout << "Please insert an input: " << endl;

       inputTest(x, y); // simple pass your variables

       cout << "Your input: " << x << " " << y << endl;
    }
```